# Is the Expected Value fundamentally a theory(em) or a mere definition\specific measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

At first, I was presented with the Expected Value as a definition. It is also a noun, and it is defined to be the implement of a specific formula. Now, I know it is a mathematical measure that is used for all sorts of necessities in probability and in other scopes, but I can't help but mix theory with reality. I mean For example, what is the difference between the following:

*What is the expected value of X?

*What is X expected to be?

The second question doesn't necessarily, theoretically, refers to the definition of the expected value, nor does it require using it. One way to determine or approximate the answer to the second question would be running various of tests (in various ways). If both question are equivalent, isn't it a little implausible that the Expected Value is solely a definition\specific measure?

This is where a question in reality is formulated and addressed in a theoretical definition, which is what makes me a little confused as for where the boundary between definition and theory is. Please don't be angry at me if I have shown ignorance in defining and referring theory and methodology. I am not knowledgeable enough in these zones and can't possibly know what I am saying or claiming is for sure incorrect. I would appreciate it if you shared your insights on it. a specific measure?

Comment: Context matters. In a mathematical context, I would consider the second question to be just an odd way or saying the same thing as the first one.

Comment: Well, this is the point of mathematics. We define things in a precise manner and then don't bother with the metaphysical and semantic meaning of their descriptions. But expected value in particular has a intuitive connection to averages (and hence an every-day concept) via for example Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: "What is $X$ expected to be?" is a phrasing that one sees mainly (only?) in low level questions.  It is usually intended as a synonym for "what is the expectation of $X$?".  Unfortunate!

Comment: @AndréNicolas 
What is the actual difference if I ask "What is the expectation of X?". 
If it does have the same interpretation, the low level is only a result of my poor English. I am not a native speaker.

Comment: I have seen variants of the phrase "what do you expect $X$ to be" in questions quoted from English-language books. The intended interpretation is "what is the value of $E(X)$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let me answer the second question first.** The expected value of a random variable has nothing to do with our expectations regarding the potential experimental results or outcomes of experiments. Consider the following example: $P(X=-1)=P(X=+1)=\frac12$. The "expected value", by definition is $1\frac12 +(-1)\frac 12 =0$, the number that we certainly will not expect as a result of an experiment related to this model.

**Experimentally** if we manage to collect many observations under the same circumstances and if we can perform the experiments independently then the average of the experimental data has to do with the theoretical expected value, which may not have anything to do with our expectations. (See. the example above.)

**Theoretically** The expected value is, by definition an integral. Probability theory can model real independent experiments performed under identical circumstances and can prove that the integral mentioned can be approximated by the average of the independent and identically distributed random variables, the model of the experimental situation.

**Probability theory is a tough discipline** because the relationship between the model and the reality modeled is much more complex than in the case of an average science.

**If you** cannot separate in your mind a model and the reality modeled then you will have a hard time with probability. I would suggest to study probability like a philosophical discipline forcing the student to learn distinguish between the theory and the related practice.